# Facing issue with elastic search in magento 2.3 cloud

Tags: catalogsearch, reindex, magento2.3.0, elasticsearch, magento2-cloud

I am facing an issue with elastic search. I can not able to reindex **catalosearch_fulltext**.

```
[2019-05-06 11:54:08] report.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined index: magento2_stg_product_1_v32 in /app/Staging/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Elasticsearch5/Model/Client/Elasticsearch.php on line 173 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Notice: Undefined index: magento2_stg_product_1_v32 in /app/Staging/vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Elasticsearch5/Model/Client/Elasticsearch.php on line 173 at /app/Staging/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61)"} []
```

Is there anyone knows how can I fix this issue. The issue is getting in only stating site. integration and production site are working fine.

I have already removed all custom attributes from **Use in search **, **Use in Layered Navigation** and  **Use in Search Results Layered Navigation**.

Still not working. can anyone help me to fix this issue?

[image]

I have already checked with the production database on the staging site.

**NOTE:** Firstly, we have added attributes manually and then after sometimes we have updated that attributes from upgrade script.

Comment: You can try to remove all indexes and then run full reindex.
`curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/magento2*`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and can confirm that deleting the indexes and reindexing, as per BaDoss comment, does indeed fix the problem. Steps taken were:

- First run `curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/magento2*` from cli
- Then `bin/magento indexer:reindex`

Bear in mind if this is run on a production site it will affect the frontend of the site while the site is being reindexed. During this time products will not be shown in categories etc